# How to create a box modal function where the image src is different than the image in the modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my box modal to display one image on the page, then display a different image in the modal that pops up when clicked on. This is what I have so far

```
<div class="row">
<div class="modal-image"><img id="myImg" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2559/4942/files/Oregon_BC.jpg?133063981068178530"alt="Oregon Base Camp Rack" ></div>
<div class="modal-image"><img id="myImg-2"  src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2559/4942/files/John_Damon_b13b257e-7888-4e2c-8c15-0a6dfa19bf42.jpg?133063981068178530" alt="John Damon Home Gym"></div>
<div class="modal-image"><img id="myImg-3"  src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2559/4942/files/TennesseeBasecamp_47f9a83d-9842-4839-bfe5-fff94eb431ac.jpg?133063981068178530"alt="Tennessee Base Camp Rack" ></div>
<div class="modal-image"><img id="myImg-4"  src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2559/4942/files/Northwestern_BC.jpg?133063981068178530"alt="Northwestern Base Camp Rack" ></div>
<div class="modal-image"><img id="myImg-5"  src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2559/4942/files/Vikings_cbf17994-7edf-4be3-8096-8f037ec5ae90.jpg?133063981068178530"alt="Minnesota Vikings Base Camp Rack" ></div>
   </div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modalA">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modalA = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
$('#myImg, #myImg-2, #myImg-3, #myImg-4, #myImg-5, #myImg-6').click(function () {
  modalA.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
})




// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if(event.target == modalA) {
    modalA.style.display = "none";
  }
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
   modalA.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

I tried adding this

```
var firstImg = document.getElementById("myImg");


var imgSwitchFunction = function() {

    firstImg.src = "newimg";
}

firstImg.onclick = imgSwitchFunction;
```

but it didn't change the modal image just the display image when clicked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this for a bootstrap modal?

Comment: The modal image's id is `img01` if you use that instad of `myImg` in your code it should change the modal image. However you can simply change the line `modalImg.src = this.src;` to something like `modalImg.src = $(this).data('newimg-src');` where your img tags need a new attribute `data-newimg-src="new/img/url.pic"` where you can store your alternate Img Urls.

Comment: I tried using the id `img01` instead of myImg and nothing changed. /I'm not quite sure how to try your second suggestion..if I change `modalImg.src = this.src;` to `modalImg.src = $(this).data('newimg-src');` where am I putting `data-newimg-src="new/img/url.pic"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to replace the newimgurl1-5 in the image tags with the urls of the images you want to display in the modal instead of the non-modal image.
Instead of picking the src tag for the modal-image to copy, this code picks a data attribute which holds an url of your liking.

```js
// Get the modal
var modalA = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
$('#myImg, #myImg-2, #myImg-3, #myImg-4, #myImg-5, #myImg-6').click(function () {
  modalA.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = $(this).data('newimg-src');
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
})




// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if(event.target == modalA) {
    modalA.style.display = "none";
  }
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
   modalA.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="modal-image"><img id="myImg" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2559/4942/files/Oregon_BC.jpg?133063981068178530"alt="Oregon Base Camp Rack" data-newimg-src="newimgurl1" ></div>
<div class="modal-image"><img id="myImg-2"  src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2559/4942/files/John_Damon_b13b257e-7888-4e2c-8c15-0a6dfa19bf42.jpg?133063981068178530" alt="John Damon Home Gym"  data-newimg-src="newimgurl2"></div>
<div class="modal-image"><img id="myImg-3"  src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2559/4942/files/TennesseeBasecamp_47f9a83d-9842-4839-bfe5-fff94eb431ac.jpg?133063981068178530"alt="Tennessee Base Camp Rack"  data-newimg-src="newimgurl3"></div>
<div class="modal-image"><img id="myImg-4"  src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2559/4942/files/Northwestern_BC.jpg?133063981068178530"alt="Northwestern Base Camp Rack"  data-newimg-src="newimgurl4"></div>
<div class="modal-image"><img id="myImg-5"  src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2559/4942/files/Vikings_cbf17994-7edf-4be3-8096-8f037ec5ae90.jpg?133063981068178530"alt="Minnesota Vikings Base Camp Rack"  data-newimg-src="newimgurl5"></div>
   </div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modalA">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```